# CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver ASP.Net Web API Spaces not removed from serialized dictionary keys

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` as the default JSON resolver for my ASP.Net WebAPI and am returning back a dictionary that is built dynamically from my controller endpoint. Clients are expecting all results to come back camel case which means there should be no spaces in keys.

So, if we have a dictionary

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"This Key": "Some Value"}
}

return dictionary;
```

I'm assuming the response returned to the client should be

```
{
    "thisKey": "Some Value"
}
```

What I get instead is:

```
{
    "this Key": "Some Value"
}
```

My understanding is camel case should not have white space. That being said, is this how `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`  was designed? Should I just implement a custom contract resolver to avoid this or can I override something in `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` ?

Here is a fiddle showing what I mean:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xbzxwm

Comment: No. It does not do that and it's not designed to. But just extend it with your own. It's not hard. You have to override 2 methods.

Comment: @AluanHaddad what do you mean it does not do that? Also, which methods should I be overriding?

Comment: You can check the implementation of Resolver at gihub. Integrally it call a util method of [ToCamelCase](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/StringUtils.cs#L155) which just only does the camel casing instead of removing space.

Comment: cool so this is how it's intended to work I'll check in on creating my own resolver which removes the spaces prior to calling ToCamelCase. Just a bit tough since camel case seems to be defined differently.. may add an issue in github although would be one hell of a breaking change at this point

Comment: There's no formal definition of camel casing, Newtonsoft did what they thought was reasonable.  Rather than a custom contract resolver, you should make a custom [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy.htm), probably inheriting from [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm), and set it on [`DefaultContractResolver.NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that's the nature of the web... just haven't really found anything that suggests camel case can allow spaces :) which is why I am considering opening an issue. I found a lot of "opinions" that spelled out no spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) . kinda went down a rabbit hole on this one so kind of arguing for the hell of it at 2am lol thx for the suggestions!

Comment: What `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` does is to modify the casing of the incoming name.  It doesn't otherwise add or remove characters.  See: [JamesNK commented on Jun 13, 2019](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2088#issuecomment-501852347): *There is no formal spec for how to do snake case. Or camel case.*